# Python + Selenium -- Can't click on the element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

There is a dropdown on my page for order search results:

```
<ul class="chzn-results" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
    <li id="selZB4_chzn_o_0" class="active-result result-selected" style=""> by popular </li>
    <li id="selZB4_chzn_o_1" class="active-result" style=""> price (from cheap) </li>
    <li id="selZB4_chzn_o_2" class="active-result" style=""> price (from expensive) </li>
    <li id="selZB4_chzn_o_3" class="active-result result-last" style=""> discount </li>
</ul>
```

I made a click, to open this dropdown:

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
order = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/span[2]/span[1]')
action.move_to_element(order).click().perform()
```

Dropdown opens. Next, I want to select "from cheap" to order objects on my page, but Selenium returns AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'.

I tried a different ways like:

```
from_cheap = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//[@id="selZB4_chzn_o_1"]")
action.move_to_element(from_cheap).click().perform()
```

or by CSS Selector. or by id, but it still doesn't make a click. 
Whats is my mistake?

Comment: Is it important that its done using `ActionChains`? How about `driver.find_element_by_id("selZB4_chzn_o_1").click()`?

Comment: It isn't works too. With NoSuchElementException error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `XPATH 1`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='chzn-results']//li[@class='active-result' and contains(., 'from cheap')]"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH 2`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='chzn-results']//li[@class='active-result' and normalize-space()='price (from cheap)']"))).click()
  ```

Comment: In this solutions I got TimeoutException.

Comment: _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` in-conjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.

Comment: Not sure why you have to delete your observation/comment which helps us to debug your issue. Inspect the HTML, traverse up the DOM and look if the element is within a `<iframe>` / `<frame>` tag

Comment: I used time.sleep(10) for wait. But it's still returns NoSuchElementException.

Comment: No, there are no frames. May be JQuery has an own specific? Click on interface raises JQuery event.

Comment: _WebDriverWait_ should handle the jQuery stuff just perfect.

Comment: Thank you! WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@class='chzn-results']//li[@class='active-result' and contains(., 'from cheap')]"))).click()
works with time.sleep()